# How to get number of rows written in spark 2.3 using JAVA?

Tags: java, apache-spark, overriding, spark2

I know we can use the use count(). But I'm trying to capture the count using sparkListener. But I'm failing to write a proper java code for the same. I've tried following the exact approach given in this [How to implement custom job listener/tracker in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463055/how-to-implement-custom-job-listener-tracker-in-spark)
But I'm not able to reproduce it in JAVA. This is something that I've tried.

```
sparkContext.sparkContext().addSparkListener(new SparkListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    private void onTaskEnd(SparkListenerTaskEnd taskEnd){
                        taskEnd.taskInfo().accumulables().name
                    }
                });
```

But it throws a lot of errors related to override and name.Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from SparkListener

Change override method private to public code should work

```
sparkContext.sparkContext().addSparkListener(new SparkListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskEnd(SparkListenerTaskEnd taskEnd){
                    System.out.println(taskEnd.taskInfo().accumulables());
            }
        });
```

Comment: It throws me this error: "The method addSparkListener(SparkListenerInterface) in the type SparkContext is not applicable for the arguments (new SparkListener(){})".Can you please help me with this ?